# Getting main() error along with first_league = League('NBA') error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I've been trying to make a simulation game. But then it keeps saying there's a problem with main() and first_league = League('NBA'). I've been using everything but it's not working.

Here's the python code:

> Python

```
import random

from player import generate_player
from team import League, Team


def main():
    # set up the data
    # set up 8 teams
    # only one manager per team
    # only one league

    players = []
    for i in range(100):
        players.append(generate_player())

    # more teams will be added later on
    teams = [
        Team('Toronto Raptors'),
        Team('Los Angeles Lakers'),
        Team('Houston Rockets'),
        Team("Golden State Warriors"),
        Team('Oklahoma City Thunder'),
        Team('Philadelphia 76ers'),
        Team('Portland Trail Blazers'),
        Team('Milwaukee Bucks'),
    ]

    for team in teams:
        # give them 5 starting players
        for player_num in range(5):
            selected_player = random.choice(players)
            team.players.append(selected_player)
            players.remove(selected_player)

    # one league
    first_league = League('NBA')
    first_league.set_teams(teams)

    first_league.play_season()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's the league class from the team module:

```
class League:
    """
    Has different teams that consists in it
    Each team has a ranking
    """

    def __init__(self, name, play_season):
        self.name = name
        self.teams = []

    def set_teams(self, teams):
        self.teams = teams

    def play_season(self):
        """
        play 30 games in the regular season
        """
        for i in range(30):
            self.play_regular()

    def play_playoffs(self):
        """
        8 teams play for the championship
         -First round  8
          -Semi Finals 4
           -The Finals 2
             -Winner   1
        """
        num_teams = len(self.teams)
        num_games = num_teams // 2

        teams_to_play = copy.copy(self.teams)

        for game_num in range(num_games):
            home_team = random.choice(teams_to_play)
            teams_to_play.remove(home_team)
            away_team = random.choice(teams_to_play)
            teams_to_play.remove(away_team)

            game = Game(self, home_team, away_team)
            winner = game.play()

            if winner:
                # home team won
                home_team.wins += 1
                away_team.losses += 1
            else:
                # away team won
                away_team.wins += 1
                home_team.losses += 1
```

Now here's the error from the console:

> Console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/josep/PycharmProjects/NBA_Fantasy/main.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/josep/PycharmProjects/NBA_Fantasy/main.py", line 37, in main
    first_league = League('NBA')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'play_season'
```

Please tell me what's wrong in the code and help me solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: What is unclear about that error message?

Comment: I don't get how main() would have a problem and the IDE doesn't list it as an error. Same as first_league = League('NBA').

Comment: What makes you think main has a problem? The problem comes when you call League, and the error there is perfectly clear. What are you not understanding?

Comment: You need to take a closer look to League class init method in your team module and make sure you create the class correctly. Looks like you are missing some parameters. You did not provide source for team module with your code and without it it is hard to help.

Comment: The league class has been posted